# 1142 INSERT command denied to user when accessing any page with a form

Tags: drupal

My Drupal 10 website hosted on OVH was working fine, but now, whenever I try to access a page with a form, I get an error on that page

The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later. Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 INSERT command denied to user 'xxxxxxx'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' for table 'watchdog': INSERT INTO "watchdog...

Any idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a MySQL user permission issue. Check if the user has required permission to perform action on drupal db.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5699061